# Error reading excel file written on Ubuntu machine in Windows (using Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas for data analysis. In one of the programs, I had to write an Excel sheet and I accomplished using `pd.to_excel()`. This was executed on an **Ubuntu machine.**

Now I was trying to read the written excel file on a **Windows machine**. I am using `pd.read_excel()`.

I am getting the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Harshavardhan R\\Downloads\\Kerala Energy Project\\Bottom-Up Modelling\threshold variation\\outputs\x07c1.xlsx'
```

The source is:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Harshavardhan R\Downloads\Kerala Energy Project\Bottom-Up Modelling\threshold variation\outputs\ac1.xlsx')
```

I can vouch that the file is present as I have opened it and checked.

Why is the file name changed to `x07c1.xlsx` in the error message? How would I avoid this problem?

Comment: Try using forward slashes (/) as you are in Windows (or) add a raw string `r` at the beginning of specifying the file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to how Windows normally expects file paths to look (with the `\`) versus how Ubuntu expects them (with `/`).

Your path, as written, has [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), specifically a `\t` (tab) and `\a` (BEL).

The second one is why you see `\x07c1.xlsx`. The `\x07` is the ASCII representation of `BEL`. If you look closely at the path you'll also notice a hidden tab character as well. This can be seen when there is only one slash instead of two:

```
\\Bottom-Up Modelling\threshold variation\\
                     ^^ This is a tab, not a "t"
```

---

You can fix this by doing a one of a couple different things. The easiest, is to make the path a raw string. Do this by putting an `r` in front of your string:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Harshavardhan R\Downloads\Kerala Energy Project\Bottom-Up Modelling\threshold variation\outputs\ac1.xlsx')
```

This reads the string literally as it exists. One note: A raw string can not end with a single backslash.

Another option is to escape your backslashes by making each backslash into two:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Harshavardhan R\\Downloads\\Kerala Energy Project\\Bottom-Up Modelling\\threshold variation\\outputs\\ac1.xlsx')
```

This works, but requires that you perform this step every time you use the path.

A final option is to use forward slashes. Windows can handle forward slashes just fine, it's just not the standard convention of the operating system

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Harshavardhan R/Downloads/Kerala Energy Project/Bottom-Up Modelling/threshold variation/outputs/ac1.xlsx')
```

---

Personally, I'd go with the raw string. It's a single character and the path doesn't "look weird" to you or other developers.

Comment: Checked all three methods and all of them work. Sticking with the raw string format.